# Two WHERE clause condition groups returned one after the other

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, sql-order-by

Our app allows admins to enter a desired where clause to return table data. One of the users wants two separate groups of criteria to come back one after the other. The only requirement is that it has to all fit in one WHERE clause so I can't use a Union.

Simplified Example:

```
Select orderID, orderDate, customerId 
FROM orders
WHERE (orderID > 10 AND customerID = 10) OR (orderID < 3 AND customerID < 3)
ORDER BY orderDate
```

The results from the first parenthesis should all come before the results of the second parenthesis. I tried using aliases for the groups of criteria, but couldn't get it working. Also, this is just an simple example, the actual WHERE conditions are a lot more complicated.

Edit: swapped inner parentheses to AND to better illustrate the issue.

Comment: The order of the results is defined by the `ORDER BY` not the `WHERE`. You'll need them to add an `ORDER BY` as well. Also, those parathesis are pointless, as everything is an `OR`.

Comment: easiest is to convert them into a case when criterias. something like: order by case when (orderID > 10 OR customerID = 10) then 0 when (orderID < 3 OR customerID < 3) then 1 else 2 end

Comment: @ThomA I should have used a better example, imagine it's (a AND b) OR (x AND y). The two parentheses groups are totally separate results in the real case.

Comment: @siggemannen The app only exposes the Where clause to the user. I could rewrite it, just wondering if this is possible in the Where clause.

Comment: You mean you allow full sql injection? sounds kinda dangerous :)

Comment: No, that's not how sets work, if you want data ordered in a particular way you have to order it.

Comment: Thanks @Stu That's really what I really needed to know. Not possible, now I can move on a find a new solution. Thanks!

Comment: @siggemannen Appreciate the concern, but only the appropriate folks can access and they have keys to the db anyway :P

Comment: @DanK, it's obligatory to mention :D But good that you are on top of the situation!